# How to share text or image from ios app to Yammer

Tags: ios, yammer

I need to share the text or image from one ios app to Yammer social network.
I am able to do login using iOS SDK of Yammer but not getting how can I share text or image from ios app to Yammer. I got the code to share text from browser but not from application.

Anybody has any idea??

Thanks in advance for your help and efforts.

Answer (score 1):

This is documented on the Yammer API page. In order to post text and attach image

https://developer.yammer.com/v1.0/docs/messages-json-post

Parameters:

body - The text of the message body.

attachmentn and pending_attachmentn - Yammer provides two methods to associate attachments with a message. Both make use of multi-part HTTP upload (see RFC1867).

The first method is the easiest, simply use file form elements with names attachment1 through attachment20. If there are a several attachments or the attachments are large it may take some time for a message to POST causing your application to appear to hang.

An alternative way is to use the Pending Attachments resource (see below for details) allowing attachments to be uploaded in parallel. Apps that support HTTP chunked transfer encoding can monitor the progress of each upload. On success each pending attachment’s response body includes an id. These pending attachment ids are to be submitted with the message using form elements pending_attachment1 through pending_attachment20. Finally, if form elements for both attachmentN and pending_attachmentN are present only the pending_attachmentN elements will be honored.

Answer (score 0):

I never used Yammer, but I wrote another app like Yammer used the given API, Yamme site should provide an API to share.